# AWS Glue crawler - Getting "Internal Service Exception" on crawling json data

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, amazon-athena

I am facing issues crawling data from S3 bucket.

File format is  form.

When I try crawling this data from S3 I get "Internal Service Exception".

Can you please suggest a fix?

When I try loading the data directly from Athena, I see the following error for a field which is an array of strings:

HIVE_CURSOR_ERROR: Row is not a valid JSON Object - JSONException: Duplicate key

Thanks,
..

Comment: Could you please verify your JSON record has no duplicates and it is valid? Also post sample records in your question if possible

Answer (score 1):

There were spaces in the key names that I was using in the JSON.

```
{
    ...
    "key Name" : "value"
    ...
}
```

I formatted my data to remove spaces from key names and converted all the keys to lower case.

```
{
    ...
    "keyname" : "value"
    ...
}
```

This resolved the issue.